# Outlook VBA - how to select a folder that is not a subfolder to Inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

[This  article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584062/select-outlook-mail-folder-using-outlook-vba) shows how to select a folder that is under Inbox in the folder tree.

I have organized mail with sub-folders that are peer to Inbox:

```
    user@company.com\Inbox
    user@company.com\Projects
    user@company.com\Projects\Alpha
```

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders) shows this approach for selecting a folder:

```
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
    Set myFolder =  myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
    Set mySpecificFolder = myFolder.Folders("MySubFolder")
    For Each mailitem In mySpecificFolder.Items  
         ..... do some stuff.....
```

where `mySpecificFolder` is derived from the default folder (Inbox), which is derived from `Namespace`.

Unfortunately, the [OlDefaultFolders enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) for `GetDefaultFolder` does not provide any that reference the root folder (presumably "user@company.com")

How can I select a folder that is not a subfolder of one of the enumerated "default folders"? The folder "user@company.com\Projects\Alpha" in my example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get folders at the same level with `Inbox` you need to get the `Parent` folder of the Inbox folder and then use the `Folders` collection to get the required folder. The [Folder.Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.parent) property returns the parent object of the specified object, typically the parent of the `Folder` object is the `Folders` collection object.

```
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set myInbox =  myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
Set inboxParentFolder = myFolder.Parent
Set mySpecificFolder = inboxParentFolder.Folders("Projects")
For Each mailitem In mySpecificFolder.Items  
     ..... do some stuff.....
```

That works only if you deal with the default store (delivery store). If you need to get the Inbox folder of the specific store in the profile, you need to use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.